# Prevent Back Button functionality in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have looked for solutions on how to disable or prevent the back button functionality, however many of these solutions do not apply to new browsers or aren't fool-proof.

I thought about creating a sessionid and giving it to a user when they login and store it into the database along with login time and givie it a status called "active". And on Logout the session status in the database will be changed to "inactive". This check will happen in all my member pages and if the user's login status is "inactive", they will be redirected to the login page.

However I do not know if this will work if the back button is pressed. Will the page still check for a session id and redirect the user even if he used the back button? Since the check will happen on the page_load, I am unsure if the page_load events will still run if I use the back button

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Wat are you trying to accomplish? Just prevent a user from obtaining site access after they logout or timeout? Prevent duplicate orders or charges for products?

Comment: @HABO prevent access to "member" pages on logout

Comment: You may see following question. It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405953/how-to-implement-prg-pattern-properly-in-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `Page_Load` event will fire when the user presses the `Back` button in the browser. So if you put the correct session checking logic in the `Page_Load` of any any member pages, then you should be good. This will account for the scenario where the user logs out, thus killing their `Session` or if there `Session` actually expires from inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you even try out some piece of code which works or not?
**On client side**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.history.forward(1);
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", keydown_handler);
function keydown_handler()
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
case 116 : // F5;
event.returnValue = false;
event.keyCode = 0;
window.status = "Disabled F5";
break;
}
}
</script>
```

**On Code Behind**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();   

   }
```

**Or,**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
   Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

**Or**,Follow it..

- [Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Attempting to disable back-button or any browser functionality for that matter is not a best practice.

For avoiding access after logout, try to transfer to another specific "you are being logged out" page after clearing session. In that "you are being logged out" page do a javascript `window.location.replace` back to your login page.